# page_template filter without a plugin

Tags: page-template

I am building a custom theme which has an insane amount of templates.  I have created an options page to allow the user to enable the page templates they wish to use. The plan is to then create a function to loop through the templates and add the ones they have enabled. I use the following function when creating a plugin but this is not being used in a plugin.  I need something like the code below to work within the functions.php document.

```
add_filter( 'page_template', 'template_selection' );
function template_selection( $page_templates ){
    $templates = get_option('templates');
    if(in_array('1',$templates)){$page_template[] = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/template1.php';}
    if(in_array('2',$templates)){$page_template[] = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/template2.php';}
    return $page_templates;
}
```

The issue here is that the filter is not working.  Any help with this matter is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "enable". The `page_template` filter runs when the page template is loaded for a page request.

Comment: The function above does nothing.  I have even added a echo 'test'; inside the function it does nothing.  The function is not firing on the pages.

Comment: It works for me when I copy/paste your code into 2016 theme `functions.php`. I get two `in_array` errors from `$templates` being false instead of an array. It seems your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I pasted the following code at the top of my functions.php document and it does nothing. add_filter( 'page_template', 'template_selection' );
function template_selection( $page_templates ){ return dirname( __FILE__ ) . 'inc/page-templates/full-width.php'; }

Comment: my functions document is completely empty except this function and I get nothing.

Comment: You have to view a singular `page` on the front end to see the `page_template` filter working. Based on your answer below, I'm guessing you were perhaps expecting to see the results on the admin screen template selector.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I found a better function which allows you to directly modify the template listing

```
function page_templates( $templates ) {
    $templates['temp/template1.php'] = 'Full Width Template';
    return $templates;
}
add_filter( 'theme_page_templates', 'page_templates' );
```